# pdf of $S_1$ given $X(t)=n$ where $X(t)$ is a poisson process and $S_1$ the time of first event

Tags: probability-distributions, density-function, poisson-process, exponential-distribution

Let $\{X(t)\sim\text{Pois}(\lambda t)\}$ be a Poisson process with parameter $\lambda$, and $0<S_1<S_2<\dots$ be the occurrence time of the events $1,2,\dotsc$ and so on.

How do can find the pdf of $S_1|X(t)=n$ and use it to find $E[S_1|X(t)=n]$?

Also, what is the pdf of $S_i|X(t)=n$ for $i=1,2,\dotsc,n$? What would be $E[S_1+S_2+\dotsb+Sn|X(t)=n]$?

Comment: What exactly does $S_1\mid X(t)=n$ denote? This seems like an abuse of notation.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Notice that $P(S_1\in ds, X(t) = n)$ is the same as
$$P(\text{First arrival in }ds\text{ and $n-1$ arrivals in (s,t]}).$$
Because these are disjoint blocks of time, the joint probability can be written as a product. Notice that 
$$P(S_1 \in ds) = \lambda e^{-\lambda s},$$
and that $X(t)-X(s)\sim \text{Pois}(\lambda(t-s)).$ Therefore
$$P\{X(t)-X(s) = n-1\} = e^{-\lambda(t-s)}\frac{[\lambda (t-s)]^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}.$$
Putting it all together  gives

\begin{align*}
P(S_1\in ds|X(t) = n) &= \frac{P(S_1\in ds, X(t) = n)}{P(X(t) = n)}\\
&=\frac{\lambda e^{-\lambda s}e^{-\lambda(t-s)}[\lambda(t-s)]^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}\cdot
\frac{n!}{e^{-\lambda t}(\lambda t)^n}\\
&=\frac{n(t-s)^{n-1}}{t^n}.
\end{align*}

I think you can get the expectation from here.
Also, apply this logic for the other $S_i$.

Comment: could you explain the logic behind P(S1∈s,X(t)=n)? what does it exactly mean and how does it become that expression?

Comment: Sorry about that. I fleshed out my answer a little.